# Finding objects in lists

Tags: python, list

I am making a function that has a list named possessions. I want a function to be able to find a given possession name and delete it from the list. I know how to delete things in python but I do not know the find.
So is there some type of:

```
find(list, object)
```

That returns the index of the objects?

Comment: what have you done so far? please provide some code

Comment: Please include everything needed *before* posting; see [ask].

Comment: If you only want to find the item to delete it, you can use `list.remove('item')` which I assume you already know

Comment: So could i write list.remove(object_name) and it would remove the first object_name?

Comment: Yes, it is a list of objects, then you can remove by its name.

Comment: `a = object(): my_list = [a]: my_list.remove(a)`

Comment: Thank you letsc you solved my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l.remove(3)
>>> l
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Just use `list.remove(<yourchoice>)`. However make sure that this will only remove the 1st matching item in case your list has multiple similar elements